# Extracting IP address from a text file in jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a text file which i read using ajax.. Now the problem is when there is two lines of string in my text file. I don't have problem when it's only one.

Here's the string

```
New Connection from: 192.168.5.10
```

No problem extracting the ip there. but the problem is if there's two line or many more.

```
New Connection from: 192.168.5.10
New Connection from: 192.168.5.30
```

Here's how I do it. It works if there is only one line of string in a text file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {

        lines = data.lines;
        var ip;
        var ipset;

        $(".dev").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

            $(".dev").append(lines[i] + "\n");

            ip = lines[i];

            console.log(getIP(ip));

            ipset = getIP(ip);
        }
    }
});​
```

The getIP function is:

```
function getIP(line) {
    var out =line.split(": ");
    return out[1];
}
```

How can I make it work getting only the IP from a string?

Comment: That DataType doesnt look JSON to me.

Comment: what does `data.lines` output?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they are separated by `newline` character. So you need to split by `newline` before you get the `IP`

```
function getIP(line){
    var out = line.split("\n"); //returns lines

    var ips = []

    for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++ ) {
       ips.push(out.split(': ')[1]);
    }

    return ips;
}
```

This function now would return a array of IP addresses.

If you just want the first one, then you can `getIP(ip)[0]`. Try and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression to extract IPs:

```
function getIP(lines)
{
   var result = lines.match(/[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}/gm);
   return result;
   //result is an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
lines = data.lines;
```

with

```
lines = data.split('\n');
```